# How to pass string arrays to Theory tests using PropertyData

Tags: xunit.net

I have a test method with the following signature:

```
[Theory]
[PropertyData("MyTestData")]
public void ProcessLines_validLines_doStuff(string[] lines)
{
   // do stuff
}
```

My property looks like so:

```
public static IEnumerable<string[]> MyTestData
{
get
{
 List<string[]> data = new List<string[]>
 {
    new[] { "1", "1"},
    new[] { "2", "2"}
 };

 var iter = data.GetEnumerator();

 while (iter.MoveNext())
 yeld return iter.Current;
}
}
```

Xunit throws a System.InvalidOperation: Expected 1 parameter, got 2 parameters

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

The properties type should be `IEnumerable<object[]>`.
The object array corresponds to the list of parameters. Even if your test method has only one parameter you need to return an array, even though it has only one element.

In your case you could specify the type as `IEnumerable<string[][]>` but that was probably what caused the confusion.

```
public static IEnumerable<object[]> MyTestData
{
    get
    {
        var data = new []
        {
            new[] { new []{ "1", "1"}},
            new[] { new []{ "2", "2"}}
        };

        return data;
    }
}
```